# Unhandled exception when pushing_back an item to a vector contained in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am finding some difficulties when I try to iterate with a vector that contains another vector inside. I have a header file which defines a structure like this:
    typedef struct Set{
        char varname[32];
        void * value;
    } Set;

```
typedef struct Setup {
    float instant;
    std::vector<Set *> SetVar;
} Setup;

std::vector<Setup *> TestCase;
```

In the cpp, I have a function that simply reads an xml file and parses the readen value to the TestCase vector, like this:

```
while(SetupHandle.ToElement()){
    Setup * newSetup = (Setup *)malloc(sizeof(Setup));
    str = SetupHandle.ToElement()->Attribute("instant");
    newSetup->instant = atof(str);

    TiXmlHandle SetHandle = SetupHandle.FirstChild("Set");
    i=0;
    while(SetHandle.ToElement()){
        Set * newSet = (Set *)malloc(sizeof(Set));
        str = SetHandle.ToElement()->Attribute("Variable");
        strcpy(newSet->varname, str);
        const char * newstr = SetHandle.ToElement()->Attribute("Value");
        newSet->value = (void *) newstr;
        newSetup->SetVar.push_back(newSet);
        i++;
        SetHandle = SetupHandle.Child("Set", i);
    }

    TestCase.push_back(newSetup);
    index++;
    SetupHandle = TC_top.Child("Setup", index);
}
```

The library compiles, but when when I use it, the program crashes in the line that says "newSetup->SetVar.push_back(newSet);". It throws an unhandled exception saying:
"Unhandled exception at 0x0430d7ba (tcmodule_psttm_isorc2014_d.pyd) in ISORC2014_CaseStudy_d.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcdcdcdc1."

Does somebody know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason why you've written this in such a C-like style? If I were you my first steps here would be to replace malloc with new, and add reasonable constructors to those classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you tried to outsmart the system by using `malloc()`. Rest assured, the system will get back at you! If you don't use `new` the objects are not constructed automatically and you will suffer from all sorts of grief. In C++, there is basically nor place for `malloc()`! The C memory functions are sometimes used as part of memory allocation facilities and, possibly, when interfacing legacy code but in no event will it be sufficient to `malloc()` a C++ object.

Comment: Thanks man! Substituting "malloc"s by "new"s fixed the problem! I was getting desperate with this bug, now it is a bit embarrasing to see how stupid the mistake was...